# Laravel Validation depending on the value of field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Let's say I have a combo box with some values

```
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="2">PQR</option>
<option value="3">XYZ</option>
```

My validation is as follows

```
'dept_id' => 'required|exists:department,id'
```

As you can see I want the dept_id field to be the id that exists in department table id column but my first option is **"All"** whose id obviously does not exists in department table.

So how can I ignore the **exists rule** if **value=0** in Laravel 5.6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 ways either create a [custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures) rule,

or have the HTML like this

```
<option>All</option>
<option value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="2">PQR</option>
<option value="3">XYZ</option>
```

and remove the `required` rule.

I recommend the custom validation rule way, an example would be like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'dept_id' => [
        'required',
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ($value != '0') {
               // check the existence of $value in db 
               // if exists return true

            }
            // return error because it was neither found in db  nor its All
            return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
        },
    ],
]);

$validatior->validate();
```